# How to get a static function into a non static funtion?

Tags: php, static, non-static

My problem is that i get this message when i register my account. (It works but that little message is a a bit ugly.)

[image]

I'm not really familiar with *static* and *non-static* so I'd like to ask how to get this:

```
$password = Password::encode($password);
```

(line 76) into a non static version.

Comment: show all the function code  at least .... inside the same class  you should use self::

Comment: "I'm not really familar with static and non static"  Have you taken the time to do any reading on the matter?

Comment: dear static function means you can not change value at the run time. so these notice has been occured.

Comment: `$pass = new Password(); $encodedPass = $pass->encode($password)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning what you got means that `encode` is not a static method. It should be called more like this:

```
$pass = new Password();
$password = $pass->encode($password);
```

Static function looks like follows:

```
private static function encode($pass) { 
...
}
```

Non static looks like this:

```
private function encode($pass) { 
...
}
```

More informations can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)